# Magento 2 : Uncaught Exception: Warning: Unknown: Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Cannot load the cart in my magento project,
magento : 2.3.2
the error_log file displays this error

```
[30-Sep-2019 08:14:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Warning: Unknown: Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner in Unknown on line 0 in /home/ai2rfdtk0dpu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Unknown: Cannot...', 'Unknown', 0, NULL)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ai2rfdtk0dpu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61
```

after a long time of loading the js console displays this error
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCwcx.png)